# Mix polymer and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, polymer

I want to open the `paper-drawer-panel` via `javascript` and `jQuery`

In the documentation is written:

> openDrawer() - opens the drawer

(https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-drawer-panel#methods)

Now i dont want to use the DOM script, i want to use jQuery:

```
<paper-drawer-panel id="pdp">...</paper-drawer-panel>
```

And onload:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#pdp").openDrawer();
});
```

How is this possible?
Thanks in advance ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its possible to do this with `querySelector` or `ElementById`:

```
document.getElementById("pdp").openDrawer();
```

or

```
document.querySelector("#pdp").openDrawer();
```